# SQLite when comparing two passwords with if they do not match while sysout prints them correctly

Tags: java, sql, javafx, sqlite

I am setting up a database with users and their passwords. I have a gui made in jfx 8, intellij IDE used

I have successfully extracted my code from my db and only when comparing them with if x == x i get the wrong password message

```
try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\java\\Java\\Just Messing Around\\MessyDB.db");
            System.out.println("DB Connected");
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM UserDB WHERE Tab = " + tabelis);
            while (rs.next()){
                int id = rs.getInt("ID");
                String  name = rs.getString("Name");
                int tab  = rs.getInt("Tab");
                String  DBpassword = rs.getString("Password");
                float right = rs.getFloat("Right");
                System.out.println("********************");
                System.out.println("********************");
                System.out.println( "ID = " + id );
                System.out.println( "Name = " + name );
                System.out.println( "Tab = " + tab );
                System.out.println( "Password = " + DBpassword );
                System.out.println( "Right = " + right );
                System.out.println();
                String password1 = pfPassword.getText();
                String password2 = DBpassword;

                if (password1 == password2){
                    System.out.println("**************");
                    System.out.println("if statement ok");
                    Parent mainMenuParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
                    Scene mainMenuScene = new Scene(mainMenuParent);
                    Stage appStage = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
                    appStage.setScene(mainMenuScene);
                    appStage.show();
                    statement.close();
                    conn.close();
                }else{
                    System.out.println(pfPassword.getText() + "  " + DBpassword);
                    System.out.println("wrong password");
                    statement.close();
                    conn.close();
                }
```

In the sys out in else, after if statement it prints identical passwords

> Else SysOut: 
>   lel  lel wrong password

Comment: Try `password1.equals(password2)`.

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Strings in Java are Objects! You are trying to check two differnt String-Objects with same content on equality. That won't work in Java at all <s>until you override the equals method of the String-class (which isn't easy possible)</s>.
To check string-values(!) for equality use

```
password1.equals(password2)
```

Comment: Thank you! I feel kind of stupid :)